# How to remove Header title in bottom nav bar - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My objective is removing the orange bar thar has the label "App name".

Currently I have a top_app_bar and bottom_nav_bar. As far as I know the orange bar is generated by the bottom nav bar.

[image: App design]

**This is the bottom nav bar implementation in the activity_main.**

[image: Activity_main.xml bottom_nav_bar implementation]

**This is the top app bar implementation in the activity_main.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top bar is called `ActionBar`. The ActionBar is a part of the default layout of the theme you are using.

**Method 1:**

You can hide the ActionBar by creating a NO ActionBar Style in the Style.xml and setting the class's style to that.

In Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then In the Manifest set the theme for the class to this `NoActionBar` Style.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

**Method 2**

Simply add a default NoActionBar Style in Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

**Method 3**

You can do it programmatically

Java

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Kotlin

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private void hide() {
    // Hide UI first
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```